# HTTPS for www and non-www only - HTTP for all subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite, https

I have certificate for single domain only, including www.
With my current .htaccess setup, I am redirecting all HTTP requests to HTTPS.
But I want to make it following:

1. Force HTTPS domain.com (www and non-www)
2. Allow HTTP only for ALL subdomains *.domain.com

Is this possible?

My current .htaccess setup forces everything to use HTTPS

```
# Force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found 1 solution:

```
# Force HTTPS www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)(domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Force HTTP subdomains
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www).+\.domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```